# How to keyframe scaling with 3D Cursor?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I've got a simple animation idea. Basically a bunch of flat planes extend into a city-like layout. This is I get when I manually scale (using 3d cursor) the buildings:

[image]
As you can see, they build from the bottom up, which is what I want.

When keyframing this, instead of scaling from the bottom (or 3d cursor), they scale from the center of each pillar individually:

[image]

How do I keyframe scaling from the 3D cursor? (Or, if possible, specifically the bottom of the pillars?)
I did research and using 3D cursor seemed to be the only way to scale it from the bottom instead of the center.

Comment: That is weird, what i would do is use shape keys and edit the pillars themselves so they always go from the ground up, instead of relying on the object scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keyframe both location **and** scale, if you want to scale in relation to the 3D cursor.

[image: Key Frame]

Since the object's pivot points are aligned with their geometric center they are technically moving, since the center position shifts up during animation.

[image: Scale Animation]

Ideally though you should position all your objects center aligned with their bottom faces though.